# grabbing value from an html input

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, input

I am trying to grab the value from an html input, and I am having trouble getting it to work, from what I was looking at doing my own research, it looks like I have the correct syntax? So I am confused.

when I console log the value, it looks like its not actually getting the value of the input.

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let grade = document.getElementById("gradeNum").value;

function getGrade() {
    console.log(grade);

    if (grade >= 90) {
        document.getElementById("gradeLetter").innerHTML = "You got an A!";
    } else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
        document.getElementById("gradeLetter").innerHTML = "You got a B!";
    } else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
        document.getElementById("gradeLetter").innerHTML = "You got a C!";
    } else if (grade < 70) {
        document.getElementById("gradeLetter").innerHTML = "You got an F! Study more!";
    }
};
```

Comment: syntax is ok. Please check spelling gradeNum in your code.

Comment: Hi, have u tried getting grade value inside function,   inside  getGrade()  ?

Comment: that worked. That is odd to me though, shouldn't it work both ways?

Comment: @karmadreamwalker nope. You need to read input value(s) again before `console.log`. `grade` won't get updated by itself

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
// let grade = document.getElementById("gradeNum").value; <-- NOT HERE

function getGrade() {
  let grade = document.getElementById("gradeNum").value;   // BUT HERE
  console.log(grade);

  if (grade >= 90) {
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. "Because" '.value' put above will be evaluated to empty string as the page loads, before the user enter any input.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

(1) If you're using typescript then [HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8791) (which is what [document.getElementById](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7645) returns) doesn't have the `value` property.
For that you'll need to cast to [HTMLInputElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9489) which [has it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9643):

```
let grade = (document.getElementById("gradeNum") as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

(2) The type of the `value` of this input element is a string, so `grade` is also a string, yet you treat it as a numer.
While `"5" == 5` is true, `"5" === 5` is false, so you might want to get the number value:

```
let grade = parseInt((document.getElementById("gradeNum") as HTMLInputElement).value);
```

(3) You set the value of `grade` as a global variable but it doesn't seem like you are reassigning it later on.
That is, when the page loads you're assigning it an empty string (as the user hasn't entered a value into the input box), and then when the `getGrade` function is invoked you don't check what is the current value.

It should be:

```
let grade: number;

function getGrade() {
    grade = parseInt((document.getElementById("gradeNum") as HTMLInputElement).value);

    console.log(grade);
    ...
}
```

Comment: its being input as a number and depending on the number, spitting out a grade letter. I have the input type as a number. but thank you, the HTMLInputElement is helpful I haven't heart of using that before

Comment: I understand that the input is for numbers, but regardless of that, when you get the value of an html input element you get it as a string. You need to turn it into a number using `parseInt(val)`, `parseFloat(val)` or `Number(val)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
grade = document.getElementById("gradeNum").value;
```

This is on the second line, and evaluated whole before the user type an input.

Instead do it like:

```
grade = document.getElementById("gradeNum");
```

And later refer to grade like this:

```
if (grade.value >= 90)
```